# Sorting buttons are not available in twinColSelect addon in vaadin 24

Tags: sorting, vaadin-flow, vaadin8, vaadin24, vaadin-core-elements

I am migrating Vaadin 8 version into Vaadin 24 and in Vaadin 8 application i have a ListBuilder addon for multiple items selection but in Vaadin 24 ListBuilder addon is not available instead of List builder TwinColSelect addon is available.

Here my issue is, In TwinColSelect addon sorting buttons are not available for sorting the selected items one by one so How to add buttons into TwinColSelect component for achieving sorting the selected items Please suggest me how to achieve selected items individual sorting functionality using TwinColSelect addon -- Thanks in advance

[Here is the ListBuilder addon component in Vaadin 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsCWO.png)
[Here is the TwinColSelect addon component in Vaadin 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixR24.png)